# Google Script Deploying web App - URL error

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

Using Google script i was able to deploy a web App and everything was working great.
[Deploying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M02dw.png)
recently the URL of the script doesn't work.

the loader of the page says: "Resolving Host"
then:

...script.googleusercontent.com’s server IP address could not be found.

[image: Error]

How to deal with this error!
Any Help please..

Comment: Any firewall blocking?

Comment: no no, i tried it from other pc, other place (different ISP), other google account... all the same! i also tried to create a new script and the same error

Comment: It seems that you try to access to "Test web app for your latest code.". So for example, for the URL of Web Apps, how about modifying the URL from ``dev`` to ``exec``? In that case, after redeploy Web Apps and retrieve the URL of ``exec``, please access to the retrieved URL. If this was not the direct solution of your issue, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, both of URL (`/dev` and `/exec`) doesn't work..

Comment: After asking a friend from other country to access the URL, it seems that the script works well from there! So! Is it about blocking google script in my country?

Answer (score 1):

After few days the url back to work again! i didn't change anything.. so i think the problem was from ISP.